# Cron Schedule not working for custom module

Tags: magento, model, cron, magento-1.9, scheduler

I have a custom module which have two cron schedule. below is the code of module's config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Inchoo_Test>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Inchoo_Test>
  </modules>
    <blocks>
        <test>
            <rewrite>
                <test>Inchoo_Test_Block_List</test>
            </rewrite>
        </test>
    </blocks>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <test>
        <class>Inchoo_Test_Helper</class>
      </test>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <test>
        <class>Inchoo_Test_Model</class>
      </test>
    </models>
    <resources>
      <test_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Inchoo_Test</module>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </test_setup>
      <test_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </test_write>
      <test_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </test_read>
    </resources>
  </global>
  <crontab>
        <jobs>            
            <test>
                <schedule><cron_expr>10 00 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>test/cron::hello</model></run>
            </test>
            <productremove>
                <schedule><cron_expr>50 23 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>test/cron::bye</model></run>
            </productremove>
        </jobs>
  </crontab>
</config>
```

and i have setup cron.sh every day at 7:00 PM. cron.php i used log inside both methods. hello creates log whereas bye didn't create log. I have run that cron mannual from aoe_scheduler and productremove works fine from admin. can someone tell me the possible causes why productremove is getting skipped.

I am little bit confused in cron working too. If i setup cron at the time of 7:00pm every day so whether it will work before 7:00 Pm or it will work for all scheduler after 7:00 PM at same day. or it will work for both before and after 7:00 PM

Answer (score 0):

the reason is a wrong cron configuration. Default magento cron.sh use to run every 5 minutes to catch up with scheduled tasks. Aoe scheduler even suggests to run itself every minute.

Take a look at Schedule->List View to see what happens with your cronjobs. If you run cron.sh only once per day you will see many tasks being "skipped"

Comment: and how can i check if any schedule is skipped or not ?

Comment: simply apply status filter to the grid

Comment: Yes but it's shows limited records all old history has been deleted, is this due to magento cron setting?

Comment: this is controlled by config field History Cleanup Every. You may find it under System->Configuration->System (Extended)->Cron

Comment: right now there is 10, how much i should  set there.

Comment: it means your history is cleaned up every 10 minutes. This value is ok, but i prefer 2 hours for not to bother the server. If values Success History Lifetime and  Failure History Lifetime are set properly you should observe enough entries.

Comment: Success History Lifetime: 60
Failure History Lifetime: 600

but i still see only limited record and that cron schedule doesn't exist in that list.

Comment: what list do you even mean? your Lifetime values are way to low. use at least 24h and increase History Cleanup if you want to see more. the most essential is of course to set cron.sh or scheduler_cron.sh (aoe) to run every minute